# Запрос к связанной таблице

Tags: hibernate, hql

Есть таблицы. Users, GroupChat - Эти таблицы описаны с помощью java кода. Между собой талицы связаны ещё одной таблицей ("groupchat_has_users"), которая описана следующим кодом:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "groupchat_has_users",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "chat_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<User> users;
```

Как в HQL запросе обратиться к таблице "groupchat_has_users"?

Comment: Какая-нить фигня типа ```List<JunctionData> junctiondata = session.createQuery("from groupchat_has_users").list();```?

Comment: Нет, точно не так. Я раньше умел это делать, сейчас не помню как это сделать. Помню чт там как-то мудрёно через джойны, и имя таблицы "from groupchat_has_users" точно не придётся использовать)

Comment: Значит, реально задача совсем другая, а не просто обратиться к одной таблице..